# cmake can't find QtCore even though already installed

Tags: kde, compiling, qt, cmake, qt4

I'm trying to install gplates-2.2.0 on Kubuntu (KDE Plasma Version 5.16.5). I installed the required packages, including libqt4-dev (`libqt4-dev is already the newest version (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu3)`). When I run `cmake .` in the GPlates directory, though, I get this error message:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindQt4.cmake:578 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /home/cta/gplates-2.2.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cta/gplates-2.2.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cta/gplates-2.2.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

`CMakeCache.txt` has the lines:

```
//The location of the Qt docs
QT_DOC_DIR:PATH=/usr/share/qt4/doc
...
//Path to a file.
 352 QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/share/qt4/include/QtCore
```

All of those directories exist, though I don't know enough about Qt to know if they have the right files. They also originally pointed to directories in `/home/cta/anaconda3`, which also existed (I changed them manually). I don't know what the problem here could be, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide release details  (is it 19.10?)

Comment: @guiverc yep, 19.10